# How can I get the previous record and the next record in an IQueryable<T> result?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I do some sorting on an IQueryable collection and fetch an item. I also have some `<a>` links on my page that I want to click to be taken to the previous and next items on the collection.

Since the ID's are **NOT** sequential, I can't just do simple arithmatic to reach them.

How can I get the previous and next items from an IQueryable given a record's position?

Comment: How are you storing the ID's currently..? can't you add them to a List<T> and sort the list? or create a SortedList? can you show what you have so far code wise so that we can provide more valid recommendations

Comment: I do **not** want to add 120,000 items to a List<T> just to get the previous item.

Comment: then I would suggest using `Ken2k` suggested answer.. that's if you are familiar with Linq Filtering..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Take()` and `Skip()` to implement your paging system. You don't need the IDs to be sequential, you'll just return objects in the order they are returned by your query.

```
var itemsPerPage = 10;
var pageNumber = 2; // Say it starts from 1

var values = query.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage);
```

Comment: How can I determine how many I need to `Take()` and `Skip()`?

Comment: @Serg, seems like you want 3 (previous/current/next), and never want to skip more than [current index - 1]. You will need special handling for index 0, because you can't skip -1, and you might need something for the last item. Work out the code for this, do extensive testing to make sure all scenarios are covered, and you're set.

Comment: You Take the number you want to display (1 if you are showing 1 at a time), and you skip everything that came before the current item. First, you would `Skip(0).Take(x)` (where x is the number you want to display). For "next", you would `Skip(x).Take(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx).

LinkedList Nodes support calling their previous and next siblings.
The constructor for LinkedList takes an IEnumerable so you should be able to implement this easily.